# Average number over hours

Tags: excel, time, average

I have two columns Calls and total hrs.  I want to know what the average # of calls per shift is.  Normally I would just =avg(Calls, hours) but one's a number and one is time.
So I tried doing avg(calls, text(hours)) and it doesn't calculate correctly.

How do I figure this?

Comment: What do you mean "hours is time"? This doesn't make sense as hours is a unit of time. Please provide an example of your data.

Comment: Avg # Calls per Shift = total number of calls / total number of shifts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HOUR` function to convert the time into hours.

So you formula would be:

```
=avg(calls, HOUR(hours))
```